# Custom precompilation location?

Tags: raku

Can I change the default precompilation location to something different than `~/.perl6`? I want to allow for using different versions of Rakudo-Star on my system without having to totally remove this directory each time I switch versions (i.e. to avoid precompilation issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason for you to remove ~/.perl6. The whole precompilation management system was specifically designed for being able to share installed modules between different versions of rakudo. Everything should just work fine without any user intervention.

If you do come across issues, that's bugs we want to fix. So please report those issues to rakudobug@perl.org or on the #perl6 IRC channel. Feel free to alert me (nine) on the IRC channel about those.

Comment: Thanks! Responding to [my question on IRC](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2017-07-18#i_14887792), Zoffix suggested it may have been to do with an [outdated `zef` module](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2017-07-19#i_14894368). So, I probably fixed it on accident. Next time I come across something weird, I'll let you know.